# Git: What is the easiest to find out in which version some functionaly was added?

Tags: git, versions

For example, I want to find out from which git version option `simple` is available for `git push`. I understand, I can analyze [Release notes](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes), but it can take a lot of time.

Comment: To be clear, are you asking about featured added to Git itself, or is this a more general question about features added to projects maintained in Git?

Comment: about features added to Git itself

Answer (score 0):

Both `git bisect` and `git blame` can help to pinpoint in which *commit* a certain change was introduced. Translating that to a release version is beyond git's scope, and will depend on how the project manages point releases.

Comment: Could be as easy as `git name-rev` if you tag consistently.

Comment: Once you have the commit, look up the git/GIT-VERSION-GEN file which has the default version string (DEF_VER, line 4) at that instant.

Comment: @Cairnarvon I see your point. But in this case how to find a line where option `simple` for `git push` was introduced?